# TFS Build (2013) - Build Stop Handling

Tags: tfs, build

I have custom codeactivities in TFS Build. One of them is a background thread that TFS Build does not know about.

> > I want to find out if there is a way for this thread to check if a "stop build" has been requested. (i.e. check on the current build status WITHOUT needing a CodeActivityContext)

(NB: I can't use the AsyncCodeActivity (and its cancel mechanism) because this still blocks subsequent tasks) 
I am currently using a heartbeat system and relying on a timeout of the heatbeat from the TFS Build flow loop but this is not fool proof.
IBuildDetail.BuildFinished exists but there is the catch 22 of if the build is finished, how do you get iBuildDetail?

Because code activities are "stateless", then using a previous "CodeActivityContext" to get iBuildDetail does not work, i.e. the context no longer exists. 
I can get to a code path of  _buildServer.GetBuild(_buildUri) 
but can't find out how to establish your current builduri (not to be confused with build definition, server, agent or number)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Good news, I found a solution

I was caught up in the BuildUri term, it turns out at the bottom of iBuildDetails, is "Uri"

This turns out to be the BuildUri

Thus code like this works ...
        static private Uri          _buildUri;
        static private IBuildServer _buildServer;

...

```
    protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
    {
        // Obtain the runtime value of the Text input argument
        string ScriptPath = context.GetValue(this.InScriptPath);
        _thisContext = context;

        IBuildDetail buildDetail = _thisContext.GetExtension<IBuildDetail>();
         _buildUri = buildDetail.Uri;    // This is the complete string
        _buildServer = buildDetail.BuildServer;
```

......
In background tthread

```
            try
            {
                IBuildDetail buildDetail = _buildServer.GetBuild(_buildUri);    // this does not work as it is not the BuildUri
                if (buildDetail != null)
                {
                    if (buildDetail.Status == BuildStatus.Stopped)
                    {
                          TerminateProcess();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                  TerminateProcess();
            }
```